# Getting seasonal variation factor from monthly sales while accounting for growth

Tags: time-series, seasonality

I have a limited set of monthly sales numbers ranging from Mar-13 to Jul-16 (i.e. current) with a large seasonal variance. To predict short term future sales I want to get a factor for this seasonal variance. Giving a years weakest month a value of 1 etc.. This is easy enough.

However the problem I have is these monthly sales also contain a near 100% yearly growth rate in sales. So as I add a new months sales, with substantially more sales compared to the same month last year, and recalculate the factors they are distorted. The more current months will be too 'strong' and the following months (that are obviously most important to the prediction) will be too 'weak'.

How can I account for this? Let me know if actual numbers are of any use and I will add them.

Comment: This probably depends on what your prediction model otherwise is like.

Comment: I don't see how. I am only looking to clean the growth portion from the 'factor'.